# element.innerHTML = something is slow in preformance, is there a faster way to change innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I need to change innerHTML to add style to PART OF text. However, I notice that using element.innerHTML = something really slows downs my function especially I have an array of >100 to change.

So is there a better way in terms of performance to add style to innerHTML?

Or is there a way to display text like innerHTML without using innerHTML?

My function just in case:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if(x[i].lastChild.className == "overlay"){
            //x[i].lastChild.innerHTML = x[i].lastChild.innerHTML.replace(/(<u>|<\/u>)/igm, "");

            if(!regexp.test(x[i].lastChild.innerHTML)){
                x[i].lastChild.style.opacity = 0;

            }else{
                x[i].lastChild.style.opacity = globalOpacityValue;

                //x[i].lastChild.innerHTML = x[i].lastChild.innerHTML.replace(/'">'+tempStore/,'"><u>'+tempStore+'</u>');

                if(x[i].lastChild.innerHTML=='<span style="color:'+textColor+'">' + tempStore + '</span>'){
                    x[i].lastChild.style.borderWidth = "thick";
                    x[i].lastChild.style.borderStyle = "solid";
                }

            }        
        }
    }
```

I am pretty sure the slow-down of performance comes from the innerHTMLs, because it happens once I take off the comments.

Comment: Use a CSS class?

Comment: Oh sorry I did not mention. The part of text needed to be changed is not fixed, so the CSS tag or <span> tag position need to changes as well.

Comment: Can you show sample HTML before and after the change?

Comment: What should I show you? A screenshot or some code? The style change in words is like: you type a code(keypress event). There is >100 overlays that have id on their own. This function underline part of the id-s according to what you type.

Comment: So if you type 101, and the id-s starting with 101 will have underlines. Like 101010101010 will become <u>101</u>010101010

Comment: OK, how do the regex and opacity and borderstyle relate to that? (It would be easier if you could provide a working snippet with 2 such overlays, so we can see it work -- it will explain more than lots of words).

Answer (score 0):

try not to use regex replacements since you are replacing fixed terms. for example update your third line to:

```
x[i].lastChild.innerHTML = x[i].lastChild.innerHTML.replace("<u>", "").replace("</u>", "");
```

check benchmarks here: https://jsperf.com/replace-string-vs-regex/6

Comment: I think this change boost the performance a bit, I can feel it. So thanks!